# Turn off autosuggest for EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there a way to programmatically turn off that autosuggest list which pops up as you type in EditText?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I had the same question but I still wanted to set this option in my XML file so I did a little more research until I found it out myself.

Add this line into your EditText.

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

Here is a Tip. Use this line if you want to be able to use the "enter" key.

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine"
```

Comment: HAVE MY UPVOTE! Actually this works really well when you want to make an EditText look like a textView.

Comment: Doesn't work in a couple of Android 4.4 phones either

Comment: API 24/Android 7.0: I replaced `android:inputType="textPersonName"` with the suggested text but it still displays the suggestion row (with the mic icon).

Comment: I used in textinputlayout with edittext still show the frequently used email

Answer (score 127):

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

also you'd better read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)

Comment: Note that "textNoSuggestions" only works for API 5 and above.

Comment: @gyller have you seen any device with API less than 5?

Comment: 0.23% of my users are on 1.6 (API Level 4).  :)

Comment: According to the documentation this should be the right to do this, but some keyboards ignore this option: http://support.swiftkey.net/forums/116693-2-bug-reports/suggestions/3684116-swiftkey-insist-on-making-prediction-even-for-edit

Comment: Though you then lose the ENTER key. If you want to be able to use ENTERs android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"

Comment: This seems to be ignored by samsung tab3s default keyboard as does filter

Comment: It disables suggestions but still shows suggestion row (have a mic option in it).

Comment: does this work combined with android:inputType="textMultiLine" ?

Comment: @RonTLV you should try

Comment: Also ignored by the AS emulator w/ Pixel XL image, API level 24.  The VISIBLE_PASSWORD work around works though.

Comment: Works well with SwiftKey keyboard.

Answer (score 70):

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

works like a charm

Comment: I would not go this route. It is a hack and you do not mention what other features of the keyboard may change when you tell it it is for password. Use "text|textNoSuggestions".

Comment: @P1X3L5 textNoSuggestions does not work for many devices. Unfortunately this hack is necessary until Google fixes that

Comment: for me it was better, it also removes the strip above the keyboard (nexus 5) which doesn't have to be true for all devices but gives better performance for some users (it also turns off the ability for speech input)

Comment: this worked to remove the `.` period char added at the end of the word if two spaces are typed after that word. I used it for the action bar searchView  

`((SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem)) .setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);`

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Other answers don't work when moving through a form and returning to a field. Google are such a bunch of dopes. Releasing such simple features that are incomplete and poorly tested.

Comment: Note that for accessibility purposes, this inputType now treats the edittext as a password and the talkback mode will announce "showing password keyboard" when the keyboard appears. This can add confusion to users that use TalkBack mode on your app.

Comment: thanks @Mr_Hmp this works well. But there is a situation, I need first letter of each word to be capital. For this we have "textCapWords", but this does not work with "textVisiblePassword". 
Please advise

Comment: If you need to capitalize first one you could do that on onTextChanged callback. this is the one that worked for my use case, no suggestions shows suggestions with the google keyboard.

Answer (score 48):

Ways to do it:

1. Programatically

```
editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
```

2. XML

```xml
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

---

If you already have some flags set, then:

1. Programatically

```
inputType = if (disableSuggestions) {
  InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS or inputType
} else {
  inputType and InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS.inv()
}
```

2. XML

```xml
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textPassword"
```

Answer (score 29):

For the android version 8.0 or above this code is not working 
and for the autocomplete textview also this code not working so i will suggest you to use below code for the **Disable the auto suggestions in 8.0 or above android vesrion use this property of edittext  *android:importantForAutofill="no"***

```
                   <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/name"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                            android:maxLength="80"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlack"
                            android:importantForAutofill="no"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                            app:bFontsEdt="light" />
```

and for the AutoComplete textview like this use this Field to Disable Auto suggestion **android:importantForAutofill="no"** :

```
      <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/autocompleteEditTextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_3sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorGrayDark"
                        android:importantForAutofill="no"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />
```

Comment: Awesome! This was the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: The only thing that works for me, thx @MaheshKeshvala , upvoted for saving my day.

Comment: Auto-fill is not keyboard auto-complete, they are different features. Auto-fill is handled by the OS, whereas auto-complete is handled by the keyboard developer (hopefully).

Answer (score 24):

The most reliable approach I have found to getting rid of autocomplete is to use

```
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD
```

on your EditText control.  As charlie has reported in a different answer on this page,

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

is the XML version of this flag.

You can combine this flag with

```
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
```

I had been using InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS without InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD, which worked for most phones, but then I came across a Samsung phone for which I was still getting autocomplete.

[Android programmatically disable autocomplete/autosuggest for EditText in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281514/android-programmatically-disable-autocomplete-autosuggest-for-edittext-in-emulat)

which suggested using InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD.

I tried this (along with InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS) and it worked.  You can see why even a phone that might not take the hint that you don't want autocomplete would *have* to allow it to be disabled for a password field.  Short of holding our breath, this might be the best way to get what we want from such phones.

On some of my devices, the font was slightly changed by this flag - most noticeably to distinguish a zero (0) from an Oh (O) more clearly, which obviously would be important for displaying a password.  But at least it worked, and the new font was not unattractive.

Even though the post on which I found this suggestion was old, the phone I tested on was very recent - a Samsung Galaxy Note II (SPH-L900) stock Android 4.1.2 from Sprint.  The keyboard selected was "Samsung Keyboard," and apparently this was the default for this phone when the customer received it from Sprint.  So this problem apparently has persisted over the years for at least some of the important Samsung line of phones.

For those of you who, like me, do not have a Samsung test device, this could be important information.

Comment: Does not work on Samsung S3 with today's firmware. Oops.

Comment: @SargeBorsch: Are you saying that TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD along with TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS still performs an auto-complete on your S3? I so, are you using the stock keyboard? I don't have an S3 but have tried my app (which uses the above approach) on an S3 in the past and there was no auto-complete. I have an S4 running Android 4.4 (Cyanogenmod) and it also does not auto-complete.

Comment: @SargeBorsch: 
If you would like to try an app that uses the above approach on your S3, here is mine:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goalstate.WordGames.FullBoard.trialsuite

Would be interested to hear whether the Check Word field at the bottom of that app (which uses the above flags) tries to auto-complete on your device.  TIA.

Comment: >"Are you saying that TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD along with TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS still performs an auto-complete on your S3?" Yes, exactly. Although there's also E-mail type, because it's an email input…

Comment: No, Check Word field doesn't invoke autocompletion. seems like E-mail flag causes the problem.

Comment: Ah.  So it is still a solution with just the two flags listed, then.  Thanks for checking.

Comment: *"I came across a Samsung phone for which I was still getting autocomplete"* -> Hey, 7 years later and TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS has absolutely no effect in **the AS emulator running a Google Pixel image**. >_<  But VISIBLE_PASSWORD works.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me

```
android:importantForAutofill="no" 
android:inputType="none|textNoSuggestions"
```

Answer (score 10):

I was getting this thing on samsung phones running 4.4.4. This solved my problem

```
android:inputType="text|textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: Same on Samsung running 8.1. Only thing that worked for me was android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"

Answer (score 7):

As this is still an issue, I'm going to post this answer. android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" works but it is undesirable, first because it's a misrepresentation of the input and second because it disables Gesture Typing!

Instead I had to use BOTH flags textNoSuggestions and textFilter. Either one alone did not work.

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textFilter|textNoSuggestions"
```

The textCapSentences was for other reasons. But this inputType kept the swipe typing and disabled the suggestion toolbar.

Answer (score 4):

OK, the problem was - in Eclipse you don't get suggestion for flag named: textNoSuggestion

And you can't set it in main.xml (where you design UI) because that attribute for inputType isn't recognized. So you can set it in code using int const:

```
EditText txtTypeIt = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtTypeIt);
txtTypeIt.setInputType(524288);
```

And thanks [jasta00](http://code.google.com/u/jasta00/) for helping me out figure answer for this one.

Comment: This does the job... .setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

Comment: Agreed, use the constant not the value

Comment: @kape123 You can't set android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" in xml because your build target is lower than 5 api

Comment: Note that for some Samsung phones the standard keyboard autocomplete does not get turned off by InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS.  One person suggests using InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD in this rather old post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281514/android-programmatically-disable-autocomplete-autosuggest-for-edittext-in-emulat

Answer (score 4):

```
    // 100% correct & tested
    txtKey = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtKey);
    txtKey.setPrivateImeOptions("nm");
    txtKey.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        txtKey.setImportantForAutofill(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO);
    }
```

Comment: very nice sulutions!

Comment: what is "nm" in the setPrivateImeOptions?

Answer (score 3):

```
android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText emailTxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
emailTxt.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

This will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the EditText's `setThreshold()` method. Set the threshold to let's say 100 when you don't want to show predictions. If you want to re-activate showing predictions, set it back to a small int like 1 or 2 depending on your needs.

Comment: there is no setThreshold() for EditText, can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want suggestion you can use "none"

**android:inputType="none|numberDecimal"**

Answer (score 0):

Find a good solution for auto suggestions with TextWatcher.
The suggestions will appear for user, but user will not be able accept them.

```
/*...*/

editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

/*...*/
}

private final TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    
    long timestamp = 0L;
    
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (!longClickable && count - before > 1 && timestamp < System.currentTimeMillis()) { // disable suggestions click
            String str = s.toString();
            str = str.substring(0, before);
            timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() + 20;
            inputText.setText(str);
            inputText.setSelection(inputText.getText().length());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};
```

Also this works good when you don't need a long click with copy/paste functionality

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, following snippet worked for me

```
fun EditText.disablePasting(){
    isLongClickable = false
    inputType = inputType or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
    doBeforeTextChanged { text, start, count, after ->
        if (after - count > 1) {
            setText(this.text)
            setSelection(this.text.toString().length)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you call your method for each edittext view in the hierarchy as:

```
private fun disablePasting(view: View?){
    if(view is ViewGroup){
        view.children.forEach {
            if(it is EditText){
                it.disablePasting()
            }else{
                if(it is ViewGroup){
                    disablePasting(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD` is used without `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS`, it will still show the suggestion bar on Gboard with the user credentials and selecting a credential would paste the clear password in the field which would be a huge security risk

Answer (score 0):

I have tried every answers in this thread, but had no luck.
Here is my *tricky* workaround.

`android:imeOptions="actionSearch"` or `android:imeOptions="actionSend"`

In fact, I needed to autofill my custom items when `AutoCompleteTextView` focused which is blank, but Android password manager(1password in my case) overrode my custom items immediately.