# Android: Multiline & No autosuggest in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to have an EditText that allows multilines and doesn't show the suggestions? I tried with this code:

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine"
```

Which I saw in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959576/turn-off-autosuggest-for-edittext), but it didn't work for me. If I try to use both at the same time, the EditText supports multiline, but the suggestions appear. Separately, they work properly.

Is this a bug in the SDK? Or maybe it is not possible to combine them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is supposed to do what you want:

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
```

Although I haven't tried it myself. "textNoSuggestions" is only available since API 5.

Comment: does'nt working if user using custom keyboard like gboard

Comment: You need to use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45097648/7487013

Answer (score 6):

If you created **Edittext Dynamically** and want to achieve **Multiline & No autosuggest** then you need to use: **setRawInputType**

```
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you man. This code works like a charm. :)

Comment: you saved my day

Comment: Perfect !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `android:SingleLine="false"` to use multiline for an EditText

Answer (score 0):

Warning: it looks like this is API version dependent.

`textFilter` option alone works for me on a tab running 3.1 (no suggestion when typing) but it does not work on a smartphone running 2.2 (still suggest when typing).

On 2.2 I use :

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

Annoying none the less if we have to check against all different API...

Answer (score 0):

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

It is working on android 2.3.x and above.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textMultiLine"
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit later than the others & the answer has been accepted, but after some testing on various devices, some keyboards ignore textFilter and textNoSuggestion, the only way that I've found to guarantee no keyboard is using textVisiblePassword

If you want it on a multi-line, you can use:

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textMultiLine"
```

Note that it has little to do with the API level, but more to do with the keyboard installed - the default Samsung keyboard on slightly older devices, SwiftKey & TouchPal definitely ignore textFilter & textNoSuggestion

I hope this helps someone else in the future

Comment: `textVisiblePassword` is the only reliable way I found, **but it triggers password management apps** (like bitwarden).