# Android programmatically disable autocomplete/autosuggest for EditText in emulator

Tags: android, emulation, android-edittext, autosuggest

Targeting Android 2.2

I have read the answers to the following questions:

[Turn off autosuggest for EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959576/turn-off-autosuggest-for-edittext)

[Android: Multiline & No autosuggest in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653271/android-multiline-no-autosuggest-in-edittext)

I have tried the following variations on the suggestions:

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER);

setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER);

setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

All of these work on most devices I've been testing (Droid X, Droid 2, Thunderbolt, Incredible) but don't work on the emulator and at least 1 device (Samsung GT i5500).

Is there any other way to **programmatically** disable the autocomplete/autosuggest for an EditText in a way the emulator and certain devices will recognize and respect?

Comment: Please bear in mind that all of these are simply hints to the input method editor. There is no requirement for any input method editor to honor them. Hence, it is all but guaranteed that there will be some pieces of hardware, or some third-party IMEs, that fail to honor the request. Now, I would expect that the *emulator* would honor them, since it has the standard input method editor, but I have not tried suppressing suggestions, either.

Comment: @gyoda were you finally able to find a solution that works on the emulator and on all devices?

Comment: @hopia Adding android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" seemed to work for all of my use cases. Also, make sure you aren't using the Japanese IME in the emulator.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've tried all the above and none of above really helped me. I've search through available *InputTypes* and I've came up with a solution, which happened to be **TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE**:

`mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE);`

From its description:

> This generally means that the input method should not be showing
>   candidates itself, but can expect for the editor to supply its own
>   completions/candidates from InputMethodSession.displayCompletions().

I haven't specified any *completions set* and as a result I'm **not getting** any **auto-suggestions**.

PS. Flag `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD` mentioned in commend above does this trick as well, but it also **disables** toggling the language in the keyboard.

Comment: This is the most appropriate solution, the others are hacks imo

Comment: All the solutions are hacky, but I think this is the least hacky :)

Comment: What if I have mentioned some other `inputType` in xml of that `EditText` as well, like *textEmailAddress*

Comment: It works. Crazy. It even disables the Android-O Autofill UI. Thank you so much

Answer (score 49):

For Vodafone 845 (2.1), huawei 8800 (2.2) devices, textVisiblePassword seems to prevent word prediction.

```
vendorId.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

or

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

[**Edit**] this answer is quite old and I don't have the environment anymore to test to get up-to-date info for comments here, sorry.

Comment: Be careful of this, on non-English keyboards this may disable some of the features such as toggling the language.

Comment: You're showing how to do it in code vs doing it in the XML layout file. But you're giving different amount of flags. Which is the correct flag(s) to use?

Comment: The above won't work for me. When I click on InputText it shows the suggestion.
Then I tried 
android:importantForAutofill="no"
It Works for me

Answer (score 25):

In the layout XML, add the following attribute to your `EditText`:

```
android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
```

If neither this, nor the above approaches work, then this is almost certainly a problem with the emulator and the other device, and you should contact the manufacturers directly.

See also: [android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions) (note that `EditText` is a subclass of `TextView`, which is why this attribute also works for `EditTexts`).

Comment: Phil, I think you meant the activity's xml file, not AndroidManifest

Comment: This answer is incorrect, you have to add following property to your EditText XML

android:inputType="textFilter"

Answer (score 7):

personally, this code help me:

```
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(null);
autoCompleteTextView.setText(address);
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to disable suggestions when I set text so I remove the adapter and after I call `setText`, I return it.

so if you want to disable suggestion just use:

```
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the class AutoCompleteTextView and set the adapter that contains nothing
[AutoCompleteTextView Class Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

example

```
 public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
   protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.countries);

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
     AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
             findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
     textView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }

   private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {""};
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"` for Edittext fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was fighting with the same problem in the emulator.  While testing, I realized that what was appearing wasn't the normal autocomplete, but a special Asian character preview (presumably because it requires multiple keys to generate one Asian character).  So I solved this by setting the language to English.  I think what I was seeing was the "Key Preview" option listed under the "Japanese IME" setting in "Language & keyboard".

I'm guessing that it would be pretty hard to disable this within an individual App without delving into the keyboard handling and language support.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the EditText's `setThreshold()` method. Set the threshold to let's say 100 when you don't want to show predictions. If you want to re-activate showing predictions, set it back to a small int like 1 or 2 depending on your needs.

Comment: EditText does not have setThreshold() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use following for disabling auto suggestion on any edittext.

```
<EditText>
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
</EditText>
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try This
android:importantForAutofill="no"

Answer (score 0):

To turn off auto corrections/suggestions on EditText programmatically:

```
 editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

Note: the aforementioned works for SearchView etal.

Answer (score -2):

'oninput' event in the input, ran the following function:

```
function RefreshAutoComplete(elm) {
elm.keyup();
elm.focus();
}
```

I run the auto complete manually, and it works

Thank you all for the help

Answer (score -3):

The answer acceted as correct is faulty. To disable auto suggest add following property to your EditText XML

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

Comment: Please read my full question. I already tried android:inputType="textFilter".