# How to reliably disable autosuggest on EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to disable autosuggest on this EditText, but all the methods outlined don't work with the Japanese IME keyboard and Swype. Is there a way to make it work correctly?

So far, I've tried everything in all kinds of combinations to no avail. Although all solutions work perfectly fine with the default keyboard, users report they still get autosuggest. This is a word game that needs word starting with certain letters, so I really need it.

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtWord"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox_bg"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textFilter|textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
        android:imeOptions="actionNone"
        >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Comment: looks dupllicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959576/turn-off-autosuggest-for-edittext

Comment: and this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281514/android-programmatically-disable-autocomplete-autosuggest-for-edittext-in-emulat  visiblepassword flag seems to work for others

Comment: I've tried visiblePassword, and although it works with most keyboards,  it doesn't work for the japanese IME, and perhaps others.

Answer (score 1):

Everything supplied to attributes like `android:inputType` are suggestions to the IME, not commands. Some IMEs will honor them, some will not. Hence, you are going to need to design your game such that either you do not care about the suggestions or you do not use an `EditText` widget.

Answer (score 0):

InputType.TYPE_NULL or 'none' (check the System level attributes for specifics) should work in most cases, but as Mr Murphy says, they're just hints, so may not work (and presumably you can't OR is it anything else).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
android:privateImeOptions="nm"
```