# hide keyboard autosuggest bar

Tags: android, keyboard

I have tried

```
android:inputType="textFilter" 


android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"  


x.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

I can see there are a lot of things to try
[Android programmatically disable autocomplete/autosuggest for EditText in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281514/android-programmatically-disable-autocomplete-autosuggest-for-edittext-in-emulat?lq=1)

Is there any method that works on all devices? For instance those commands above don't work on my device, yet work for other people.

Comment: You mean on your keyboard?

Comment: Yes, to clarify, I'm using a softkeyboard, and the autosuggest is on top of it.

Comment: That's an issue with the keyboard, not the EditText

Comment: Apologies, I will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

This works, even though the xml version does not. Probably won't work on all device I install it on. Weird issue.

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: It takes up too much room on the screen. Seeing as the keyboard already takes up half the screen. It's not needed.

Comment: Not everyone and not every device uses the same IME though.

Comment: True, however this app will always be used on the same type of tablet, same software etc.