# How to disable auto-complete and auto-correct of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to disable auto-complete and auto-correct in my editText field. I found this solution which disabled everything:

```
this.setInputType(this.getInputType() | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
            | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER);
```

That is fine but now I need to change my keyboard from normal alpha numeric to email. Unfortunatelly function above removes this option. When I remove parameter EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER, I can set an email keyboard but auto-complete is back as well.

How can I disable auto-correct/complete and have email keyboard at the same time?

Comment: Check this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959576/turn-off-autosuggest-for-edittext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line into your EditText.

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

Here is a Tip. Use this line if you want to be able to use the "enter" key.

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine"
```

Check this link too:

[Android programmatically disable autocomplete/autosuggest for EditText in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281514/android-programmatically-disable-autocomplete-autosuggest-for-edittext-in-emulat)

Answer (score 8):

Try this... Add to your xml.

```
     android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn off auto-complete and auto-suggestions on EditText (SearchView etal.) programmatically:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```