# Disable auto-suggest does not work for non-English keyboards

Tags: android, autosuggest

I have set InputType to TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD to my EditText view to disable auto-suggest. It works fine when language selected is English but when I change language to Japanese, auto suggest is not disabled.

Any idea how to disable auto-suggest programmatically irrespective of the language selected and device type?

Comment: please have a try at all answers over [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281514/android-programmatically-disable-autocomplete-autosuggest-for-edittext-in-emulat) and [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281838/how-to-disable-displaying-suggestions-on-the-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Nonprogrammatically:

Go into the XML file, find the EditText, change it with `android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"`.

Programmatically:

```
yourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) for more details.

Comment: Try only using `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS`, and see if that works.