# How to suppress dictionary hints while entering text?

Tags: android, dictionary, keyboard, android-edittext

I am stuck with dictionary hints while entering password (or any other text field). I am doing it in this way:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

But anyway when user selects keyboard predictions as "on" - during password entering it shows dictionary hints, which is stupid for passwords!

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I believe the keyboard/inputmethodservice that you are using is misbehaving. It can and should detect edittexts marked as password and prevent suggestions for them. Are you using the default system keyboard ?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959576/turn-off-autosuggest-for-edittext. Similar problem. surprising answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> textNoSuggestions 0x00080001
>   Can be combined with text and its
>   variations to indicate that the IME should not show any
>   dictionary-based word suggestions. Corresponds to
>   TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS.

More Info Here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AutoCompleteTextView_inputType

Use the IME Options for the Edit text.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edtPass"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:imeOptions="textNoSuggestions"/>
```

More about Input Types:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputMethod)

Also Do take a Look at here http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d3c055137498bbc9?pli=1

Comment: In some HTC Sense Devices(Not in all but in some specific), this doesn't seem to work. This is among the rarest. I have a HTC Wildfire and HTC Magic. I'm getting the normal android behavior in these ie.) no suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `setTransformationMethod()` method like this:

```
editText.setTransformationMode(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

[android.text.method.TransformationMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTransformationMethod)

Or whats also possible is to set the `android:password` value to `true` in your layout XML like this:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:password="true"/>
```

Comment: but this method just reformats input to asterisk alike symbols, r u sure that it will also suppress dictionary hints?

Comment: not sure but I think it will work and if not maybe in combination with `android:inputType="textPassword"` or the code you use now

Comment: Nope it doesn't work neither setting "android:password" nor setTransformationMethod

Comment: Maybe the answer of AndroidKid works and otherwise it might be the keyboard you are using, you should try it on a different phone / the emulator

Answer (score -1):

Check it out!

reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#AutoCompleteTextView_inputType

[1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#AutoCompleteTextView_inputType): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULX2a.png **See the picture**

XML:

```
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>
```

JAVA

```
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```