# is there a way to check whether IME Predictions are enabled or not?

Tags: android

I have an app, where I have to disable some buttons, if IME predictions are enabled. Is there a way to check this from app?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: i can't under stand your question.please explain another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you mean by IME predictions is the autosuggest popup that appears on top of the keyboard.

The only way to do this is to check the [inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) of the fields you have. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959576/turn-off-autosuggest-for-edittext) shows how to enable the autosuggest fields, but, in your case, you will have to call [getInputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getInputType%28%29) and check the return value, like so:

```
if(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS & editText.getInputType())
//enable buttons
```

Comment: @Yamuna what about you mark the question as resolved, then? This would help others identify the correct solution.