# Clear suggestion text in android

Tags: android

i setOnQueryTextListener for my edittext view. If there is no search item mean it will show one alert box. But some time if enter numbers fastly from keyborad remaining number are display at the bottom of the screen.like this[image]

how can clear that bottom numbers.

Comment: turn off suggestion for your app from keyboard

Answer (score 1):

```
SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(this,
        HelloSuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY, HelloSuggestionProvider.MODE);
suggestions.clearHistory();
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

A Suggestion will be to turn off the auto-suggestion for the `EditText`.

Add this line into your `EditText`.

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

**Or**

```
EditText edit = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.edit);      
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

See this for more answer [Turn off autosuggest for EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959576/turn-off-autosuggest-for-edittext)