# Turn off autosuggest for not-EditText in Android?

Tags: android

I have some `View` which fills entire layout. Activity listen keyboard events in `dispatchKeyEvent` and do something with this view (immediately, once for each character). But if any kind of autocompletion or auto-spellchecking or whatever is ON - activity will not receive anything until user commit his input. That is unacceptable.

[There is solution for `EditText`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959576/turn-off-autosuggest-for-edittext).

What can i do to force activity/view act like `EditText` with input type `textFilter` (or `textNoSuggestions`, or `'textVisiblePassword)`?

P.S. i can place hidden `EditText` somewhere in my layout and most likely it will work acceptable. but here could be some side effects and the solution is not beautiful at all.

Comment: "i have some view" - what view, some code if cusrom one?

Comment: That does not matter at all. It could be 'TextView' with log of all keys pressed or 'GLSurfaceView' runing the game with keyboard input. The important thing is that the screen is filled with something entirely and activity handle key events.

Comment: what does your view returns in onCreateInputConnection ?

Comment: Never heard about this. But I've just read spec and it looks very promising! Can you give an example?

Comment: don't have any, see TextView.java for a default implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved.

Thanks to pskink for key clue. [Important link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html).

The fact is that keyboard need to get someеthing called `EditorInfo` from view, which is in focus. It allows `EditText` with certain `inputMethod` works properly.

So we just need to copy that behavior. You can use any view. I have override `LinearLayout`, use it as root viewGroup in xml and mark all views as

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

and only root has those tags "true". Not sure if both tags important.

then you need just to override two methods in your view

```
public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
    return true;
}

public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD |
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD |
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS |
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE;
    outAttrs.imeOptions |= EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION;

    return new super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs)
}
```

This will solve most problems. There also some improperly implemented keyboards (for example Emoji Keyboard (at 03/03/14)) which ignores `EditorInfo`. If you want - you can overcome even this with custom `InputConnection`, which `extends BaseInputConnection` - just override

```
public boolean setComposingText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition)
```

and you will get callback on each composing-event. Not really comfortable, but works at least. And this custom `InputConnection` must be returned from view's

```
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs)
```

UPD1. Custom `InputConnection` also usefull with Samsung keyboards.