# EditText input is cached for auto-completion even if disabled

Tags: android, android-edittext, samsung-mobile

I use an EditText widget to get user input which is sensitive, i.e., the input should not be stored for auto-completion lateron.

In the code I tried several combinations of

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

or

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

or even both.

It works on almost all my test devices, except several Samsung phones and a single Sony device. For example on the Samsung Galaxy 4 the mechanism works as expceted, but the Samsung S3 ignores the EditText's configuration and presents the sensitive input for auto-completion lateron. Of course, Google's documentation does not give any information about how to reliably disable the auto-completion cache for an EditText. Any idea why this works for some devices but not for other devices? Thanks.

Comment: did you find anything on this yet?

Answer (score 0):

[Turn off autosuggest for EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959576/turn-off-autosuggest-for-edittext)

Check this link .

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

Comment: You misunterstood the question. I don't want to turn of autosuggest for MY EditText. Somehow the information entered in MY EditText is cached for autosuggest of OTHER EditTexts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your activity:

Java:

```java
edittext.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

or with the XML attribute:

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```