# Disable caching of input text in EditText without disabling dictionary autosuggestion

Tags: android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events, autosuggest

I want to disable caching of entered text in EditText in Soft keyboard with autosuggestion of keyboard functionality on.I tried below code

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
```

But it disabled the keyboard suggestion itself.I tried `android:inputType="textFilter"`mentioned on link [Turn off autosuggest for EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959576/turn-off-autosuggest-for-edittext) But it didn't solved my purpose (I just want to disable caching not keyboard suggestion). Please help.