# how to avoid the suggestions of keyboard for android in react-native

Tags: react-native

Hai i am struggling with keyboard problem in android, when i want to type any thing in text input it show some suggestions in keyboard, I don't want those suggestions, Can any one help me that how to avoid those suggestions.
[image]

Any help much appreciated, the above image from nexus 6.
Here is my TextInput code

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.TextInput}
    value={this.state.currentWord}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({currentWord:text.trim()})}
    placeholder="Type Your word here"
   autoCapitalize='characters'
  autoCorrect={this.state.autoCorrect}
  autoFocus={this.state.autoFocus}/>
```

In state i declare autoCorrect to be false

Comment: Have you set autoCorrect to false?

Comment: yah but it is not working in android, In IOS it is working

Comment: Could you post the code for your TextInput? When I try it in the emulator autoCorrect={false} works fine.

Comment: Above i attched the code for TextInput

Comment: Sorry, but i can't reproduce your problem. It works exactly as it should in emulator.

Comment: Had the exact same problem on real device Samsung note 3 (android 5). Don't have this problem on Nexus5x (android 6), or super cheap android 4.4 device. If someone had an explanation... On each device : app  has `disabled` `autoCorrect` and all devices had `auto-suggestion active`.

Comment: [From a trusted name](https://davidwalsh.name/disable-autocorrect): _"While I love these features, they aren't always applicable and when they aren't, users get frustrated"_

Comment: Now if I could just find a way to re-enable this when a developer has disabled it...

Comment: 2 years later and error is still present!

Answer (score 18):

When using `autoComplete="false"`, React native sets the underlying native android input type to `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS` and clears out `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT`, effectively telling the system not to offer any suggestions (see [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/f3507f99f18f8a26d67289fbad4d52e1f15a294c/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textinput/ReactTextInputManager.java#L378)). This is the recommended way of disabling text suggestions per the [Android reference guides](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS).

The problem is it appears that some (or many?) HTC devices do not honor this setting. From my research, it appears some Samsung devices might not support this either. It is reasonable to assume that other manufactures will not honor this setting - which flat out just sucks. This is one of the big problems with Android - somehow they didn't learn from Microsoft - that sleazy manufacturers will destroy the reliability of your products and it takes years (a decade, roughly) to even begin to undo the damage `</rant>`. (note: I'm an Android fan).

According to Daniels answer it appears someone had success setting the text type to use `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER` - which tells the device that your input is being used to filter a list of items. Lets try to modify the existing text input and see if it works - then you can build our own if you want:

1. You need to find the file `ReactTextInputManager.java`. From the React Native folder, it will be located at this path:

   ```
   [react-native]/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textinput/ReactTextInputManager.java
   ```
2. Around line 378 you will find a method called `setAutoCorrect` - update it to the following:

   ```
   public void setAutoCorrect(ReactEditText view, @Nullable Boolean autoCorrect) {
       // clear auto correct flags, set SUGGESTIONS or NO_SUGGESTIONS depending on value
       updateStagedInputTypeFlag(
           view,
           InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER,
           autoCorrect != null ?
               (autoCorrect.booleanValue() ?
                   InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT : (InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER))
               : 0);
   }
   ```
3. Build your app and test. If it doesn't work, try removing both instances of `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS |` (**including the pipe**) from the above code and try again. If that doesn't work, I think you're out of luck.
4. If it *does* work, then you can either **a)** instruct everyone on your team how to modify the react native component before building (hacky and unreliable), or **b)** build your own text input component. You should be able to copy and paste the existing TextInput code and shouldn't have to write much native code at all - mostly just renaming things. Good luck.

**Update:** going further down the rabbit hole, you can also try the setting `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD`. So here is the kitchen sink - I'm assuming you can read the code well enough to play around with different combinations of input types:

```
public void setAutoCorrect(ReactEditText view, @Nullable Boolean autoCorrect) {
    // clear auto correct flags, set SUGGESTIONS or NO_SUGGESTIONS depending on value
    updateStagedInputTypeFlag(
        view,
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD,
        autoCorrect != null ?
            (autoCorrect.booleanValue() ?
                InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT : (InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD))
            : 0);
}
```

It helps to understand that the method signature for `updateStagedInputTypeFlag` is the following:

```
updateStagedInputTypeFlag([view], [flagsToUnset], [flagsToSet]);
```

**Update 2:** There are lot's of "input type" flags you can use, [see a full list here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AinputType). Feel free to try others - you might stumble upon one that works. You should be able to modify the code from my first update above.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks to you I learned about Android (*I'm from iOS world*) more than I expected and in just few seconds. I will test (just need to borrow my colleague's Samsung device).

Comment: I learned a lot too. Java is not my forte, so I hope this works or at least sends you in the right direction. I also just realized I left out some `InputType.`'s in my original answer - I've updated the code. Also, in keeping with the vein of this answer, you can try any of the input types described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AinputType).

Comment: It did not solve Samsung Note 3 issues. I will try to get more devices in my hands to see whether it occurs other Samsung and other devices. Anyway for a free app I already feel fully satisfied to be aware of why and how handling this issue.

Comment: Your next best option is to go down that [list of input types](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AinputType) and try every single one until you find one that works. Another place suggested using `<input name="password>` (note the "name" attribute, not "type"). Also worth noting that I don't think you can disable suggestions on API < 5.0. Note 3 uses Jelly Bean, which is 4.3. You are definitely not likely to find a solution for that. Sorry man :(

Answer (score 11):

if anyone has this problem, setting **autoCorrect=false** and **keyboardType="visible-password"** hides the suggestions in android

Comment: This works great on some devices (Pixel 2) but not on others (e.g. Galaxy S7).

Comment: Works for Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite

Answer (score 3):

You can set the TextInput to Set autoCorrect to false.

Answer (score 3):

My solution was using keyboardType={'visible-password'} when the password is visible

```
  <TextInput
    onChangeText={onChangeText}
    label={label}
    autoCapitalize='none'
    value={password}
    secureTextEntry={isPasswordVisibile}
    keyboardType={this.state.isPasswordVisibile ? undefined : 'visible-password'}
  />
```

Comment: though this works for hiding the suggestions but secureTextEntry doesn't work after the password is made visible and then back hidden.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to write your [own Android `TextView` wrapper](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html), that sets the [correct input type](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AinputType). [See this stack overflow post for more information on the android part.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959576/turn-off-autosuggest-for-edittext)

Comment: Thank you you are right there is no better way. Such a shame manufacturers create a mess in Android. Google is going to change the deal soon so that we will be able to deliver better apps.

Answer (score 0):

Our fix/hack was to simply change the input`s type from text to email and back to text.