# Android hide suggestions bar

Tags: android, react-native

Using react-native's `TextInput`, i can get the following by setting `autoCorrect={false}` :
[image: Keyboard]

That is, it effectively hides the suggestion's content but not the bar. Is it possible to hide the suggestion bar too? I have heard about `textVisiblePassword` but it seems a hack to me since the text field is...well, not a visible password. I just want to use that space for my app (specially in smaller phones).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37818910/4417447
Check this one.

Comment: I will try that out tomorrow, thanks! I took the snapshot in Genymotion, will test on a physical device too.

Answer (score -2):

When developing for 2.0+, the supposed way is setting

> android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

if still it doesn't work in some devices than you can also try

> android:inputType="textFilter"

for further refer this [Android official Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS)