# Keyboard's suggestions when "secureTextEntry" is false

Tags: react-native

I use RN 0.52.2,
I have TextInput for users password:

```
<TextInput
 ref={(input) => {this.passwordInput = input}}
 value={this.props.userPassword}
 returnKeyType={'go'}
 secureTextEntry={this.state.hidePassword}
 autoCorrect={false}
 autoCapitalize={'none'}
 placeholder={'Пароль'}
 placeholderTextColor={THEMES.blue.gray}
 style={styles.textInput}
 onChangeText={this.props.updateUserPasswordFromSignUp}
 underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
 autoComplete={false}
/>
```

And when **secureTextEntry** changes to false , I will see suggestions on the keyboard, but I want avoid suggestions.

P.s.: I try create mobile app for android and ios both

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to avoid the suggestions of keyboard for android in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001070/how-to-avoid-the-suggestions-of-keyboard-for-android-in-react-native)

Comment: Worth noting that certain Samsung Android devices ignore the flag that disables these suggestions.