# Disable fill suggestions on React Native Android

Tags: react-native, autofill

when I use my application on my Android (Xiaomi), I have this kind of suggestion that appear below (or above) my TextInputs even when they are textInputs that can receive codes, postal addresses, ...

I already tried "autocomplete=off" and I saw that there was a hack with "keyboardType=visible-password" but I can't afford to use this keyboard for some fields.

How can I disable this kind of autocomplete for my TextInputs?

[image: Fill suggestions that I want to rid off]

Thanks,
Viktor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to avoid the suggestions of keyboard for android in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001070/how-to-avoid-the-suggestions-of-keyboard-for-android-in-react-native)

Comment: @Abe No. My problem is only that i found theses suggestions annoying and I don't know how to remove them.

Comment: That is exactly what the question is in the other thread