# Disable "input assistance" for editText

Tags: android

I'm programming a vocable trainer for my son. It works fine.
He must input the vocables in an editTextfield.

When he enters the first letters of the translated word, the "input assistance"
upper the virtual keypad shows the best suggestions. I thinks this is the
default way of entering text in android.
Of course he should not see the suggestions. He should type in the word without help! Is there a way to hide the suggestions?

I hope you know what I mean.

I would be glad to get an answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn off autosuggest for EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959576/turn-off-autosuggest-for-edittext)

Comment: Add this line inside edit text ..
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

Answer (score 0):

editText.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);