# Turn off auto suggest of numbers for EditText?

Tags: java, android, xml

Number suggestions pop up when you tap at edittext. Is there a way to receive input as number but at the same time prevent number suggestions from displaying?

I have found something similar like this. but it accepts text not numbers!

[Turn off autosuggest for EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959576/turn-off-autosuggest-for-edittext)

below are not working since it only accepts texts and then removes suggestions.

```
android:inputType="textFilter" 
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

I have tried

```
android:inputType="number|textNoSuggestions"
```

It results to accepting non-numeric symbols and does not remove suggestions either.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: try `android:digits="1234567890"` with `android:inputType="textFilter" 
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`

Comment: does not work either. The suggestions still pop up. it also calls keyboard including a-z characters since the inputType is not a number. But thank you anyway

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Android O has the feature to support Auto-filling for fields**,Just only use this in your xml, It will disable autofill hints

```
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
```

Comment: how about the support for lower API target ? should android:autofillHints="@null" be of no importantance?