# Prevent android from saving and retrieving passwords when typing on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I prevent this from happening, multiple users are going to use the app on the same device and I do not want all of them having access to some places

[image]

Comment: Have you `android:inputType="textEmailAddress"` in your EditText?

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959576/turn-off-autosuggest-for-edittext

Comment: I have android:inputType="textPassword"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You simply just add one property to your editText view

```
android:inputType="textPassword|textNoSuggestions"
```

and you are done.

if it is not working for you there is another alternative solution. You can turn off autofill programmatically.

You can try to this.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           disableAutoFill();
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        private void disableAutoFill() { 
            getWindow().getDecorView().setImportantForAutofill(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO_EXCLUDE_DESCENDANTS);
        }
    }
```

Comment: a have added one more alternative solution check it. It will work

Answer (score 5):

If none of the suggestions worked, like with me, try this as a last resort:

```
android:importantForAutofill="no"
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me
https://www.addictivetips.com/android/google-autofill-settings-for-apps-android/

Disabling the autofill from Google, but I did not find how to do it just for my app

Comment: how is it related to the code?