# Turn off autosuggest for EditText on Samsung devices

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext, infobubble

Since the last update of my Samsung galaxy Tab A, some EditTexts (those who have "name" as id) show an "autosuggest bubble" when they are selected.
[image]

I tried to remove them with

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

or

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

or

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

as shown on [Turn off autosuggest for EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959576/turn-off-autosuggest-for-edittext), but that had no effect.
Do you think these bubbles-suggestions come from Samsung?

If I rename the EditText id to "namo" instead of "name", it works. But this is not a valid solution for me.

Comment: android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"

Answer (score -1):

Try the below:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
```