# EditText "Missing autofillHints attribute" and "Missing accessibility label"

Tags: android, android-edittext

> Missing autofillHints attribute less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Inspection info:Specify an autofillHints attribute when targeting SDK version 26 or higher or explicitly specify that the view is not important for autofill. Your app can help an autofill service classify the data correctly by providing the meaning of each view that could be autofillable, such as views representing usernames, passwords, credit card fields, email addresses, etc.  The hints can have any value, but it is recommended to use predefined values like 'username' for a username or 'creditCardNumber' for a credit card number. For a list of all predefined autofill hint constants, see the AUTOFILL_HINT_ constants in the View reference at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html.  You can mark a view unimportant for autofill by specifying an importantForAutofill attribute on that view or a parent view. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setImportantForAutofill(int).  Issue id: Autofill  More info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill.html
>
> Missing accessibility label: provide either a view with an android:labelFor that references this view or provide an android:hint less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Inspection info:Editable text fields should provide an android:hint or, provided your minSdkVersion is at least 17, they may be referenced by a view with a android:labelFor attribute.  When using android:labelFor, be sure to provide an android:text or an android:contentDescription.  If your view is labeled but by a label in a different layout which includes this one, just suppress this warning from lint.  Issue id: LabelFor

[warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAEj5.jpg)

This warning started to appear after upgrading targetSdkVersion from 25 to 26. Also my minSdkVersion is 17. I don't want to use autofillHints and android:labelFor.

I tried to add the following codes to my app separately, but after adding these one, the other warning still remains.
How can fix this warning?

```
<EditText
    tools:ignore="Autofill"/>
```

---

```
<EditText
    tools:ignore="LabelFor"/>
```

Comment: try: android:importantForAutofill="no"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56320742/7056683
checkout this answer

Comment: "Attribute importantForAutofill is only used in API level 26 and higher"  My minSdkVersion is 17  @Lucky

Comment: Well you could just set it like this: android:autofillHints="yourval"
Take "yourval" from here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAutofillHints(java.lang.String...)

Comment: Same warning. "Attribute autofillHints is only used in API level 26 and higher"

Answer (score 0):

Using the newer versions of Android Studio, I had the same problem,
If you do not need it use:

```
<EditText
    tools:ignore="Name"
    .../>
```

If you need it, it works this, but the error does not disappear:

```
<EditText
    android:hint="Name"
    .../>
```

I think is a bug, because some time ago worked fine.